# Is there away to make this switch statement shorter?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
  switch($act1){
     case "SUBSCRIBE":
     $error = "false";
     break;
     case "SUB & LIKE":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case "LIKE & COMMENT":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case "DISLIKE":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case "COMMENT":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case "LIKE":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     default:
    $error = "true";
    $error_01 = "true";
    break;  
 }
 switch($act2){
     case "SUBSCRIBE":
     $error = "false";
     break;
     case "SUB & LIKE":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case "LIKE & COMMENT":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case "DISLIKE":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case "COMMENT":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case "LIKE":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     default:
    $error = "true";
    $error_02 = "true";
    break;      
 }

switch($act3){
     case "SUBSCRIBE":
     $error = "false";
     break;
     case "SUB & LIKE":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case "LIKE & COMMENT":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case "DISLIKE":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case "COMMENT":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case "LIKE":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     default:
    $error = "true";
    $error_03 = "true";
    break;      
 }

 switch($act4){
     case "SUBSCRIBE":
     $error = "false";
     break;
     case "SUB & LIKE":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case "LIKE & COMMENT":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case "DISLIKE":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case "COMMENT":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case "LIKE":
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     default:
    $error = "true";
    $error_04 = "true";
    break;  
 }
```

How can I make this whole thing shorter ? I mean I tried to use a for loop, but I had massive problems with that, cause I am quite new in all that. I hope somebody can help me out, here. Also do you think there is a better form of valadation, I want to check if the data given by the user is the same as the options the form offers, so he can't submit something that the form doesn't contain, to prevent mysqli injection. All this looks very unserious for me, and not very safe.

Comment: put the values into an array. something like `$response = Array("SUBSCRIBE"=>"false",...);` then `$error = $response[$act1];`

Comment: or make use of `in_array()`;

Comment: I have commented on another post of I. Dynin. I basically said; there are many things wrong with the code, but the issue raised in the question isn't one of them. I referred him to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Then I left. When I came back the question was gone and he had commented: "I am only 20". Clearly my comment was seen as bullying. That was never my intention. I do apologize. Since there is no private messaging system, I have to make this apology publicly, like this. All I wanted was to discuss the code. I will learn from this and be nicer next time.

Comment: Huh, no I never saw your comment as something bad, I just don't like when people say there is so much wrong, and don't give some reasons, cause yeah I already mentioned there that I am not good in php, and I have even problems setting a cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write it shorter because all of your actions are the same for every set except default.

Consider the following, I refactored your first switch statement, this will work exactly the same way as before.

```
switch($act1){
    case "SUBSCRIBE":
    case "SUB & LIKE":     
    case "LIKE & COMMENT":   
    case "DISLIKE":  
    case "COMMENT": 
    case "LIKE":
        $error = "false";
        break;      
    default:
        $error = "true";
        $error_01 = "true";
        break;  
}
```

### Be More Dynamic

A more dynamic way to look at this, sort of based on what Andrew Andrew posted, is you could use a loop to loop through all the acts and check them for errors.

PHP is a great tool to make dynamic scripts that allow you to not repeat so much code manually, and can handle the situation you are in automatically, possibly without future code editing. Here is how I would have done your situation

```
    //declare a whitelist of things that should not produce an error
    $whiteList = [
        'SUBSCRIBE',
        'SUB & LIKE',
        'LIKE & COMMENT',
        'DISLIKE',
        'COMMENT',
        'LIKE',
    ];

    //add all of the acts to an array to loop over
    $acts = [$act1, $act2, $act3, $act4];

    //by default error is set to false
    $error = "false";

    foreach($acts as $key => $act) {
    //if key is less than 9, add a 0 to the front, to get error_01, error_02 etc, if its above 9 then just add the number itself like error_10
    $errorKey = $key < 9? "0{$key}" : $key;

    //check if value from act is in the whitelist declared above, if its not, set `$error` to true and set `$error_*` (with key) to "true" as well.
    if(!in_array($act, $whiteList)) {
        $error = "true";
        ${"error_$errorKey"} = "true";
    }
}
```

This way is dynamic, as you can add more acts to the `$acts` array and it will automatically set an `error_##` based on where it appears in the array.

### The problem: Error checking

Retreiving this error later would be a much more difficult thing to do, as you don't know which error was set or anything. So to combat that, you could just scrap the `$error_##` part entirely and only use `$error` as a variable.

```
//declare a whitelist of things that should not produce an error
$whiteList = [
    'SUBSCRIBE',
    'SUB & LIKE',
    'LIKE & COMMENT',
    'DISLIKE',
    'COMMENT',
    'LIKE',
];

//add all of the acts to an array to loop over
$acts = [$act1, $act2, $act3, $act4];

//by default error is set to false
$error = "false";

foreach($acts as $key => $act) {
    //check if value from act is in the whitelist declared above, if its not, set `$error` to true and set `$error_*` (with key) to "true" as well.
    if(!in_array($act, $whiteList)) {
        $error = "true";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you want to set $error to false in every iteration. When you exit the loop, it will be true or false based only on the last iteration ($act4). This is different than the original code. $error = false should be moved to before the loop.

Comment: @EdmCoff Nice catch! Thank you!

Comment: thats, very good but value stands for the amount of the acts or what ?

Comment: Yes, you should look into [foreach loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Basically, `$value` inside the loop is set to whatever the individual `$act` is, so on the first loop it's `$act1`, then `$act2` etc for however many that you add.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help ^.^

Answer (score 2):

Another approach.

```
<?php
// allowable keywords
$whiteList = [
    'SUBSCRIBE',
    'SUB & LIKE',
    'LIKE & COMMENT',
    'DISLIKE',
    'COMMENT',
    'LIKE',
];

// if $act1 is in the list of allowable keywords then set $error = "false"
if (in_array($act1, $whiteList)) {
    $error = "false";
} else {
    $error = "true";
    $error_01 = "true";
}

if (in_array($act2, $whiteList)) {
    $error = "false";
} else {
    $error = "true";
    $error_02 = "true";
}

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a function to handle the same logic and apply the `switch` statement there.  Instead of repeating the same `switch` statements with identical logic, you can just call a common function.

```
function getError($act_in) {
    $error = "";
    switch($act_in) {
        case "SUBSCRIBE":
        case "SUB & LIKE":     
        case "LIKE & COMMENT":   
        case "DISLIKE":  
        case "COMMENT": 
        case "LIKE":
            $error = "false";
            break;      
        default:
            $error = "true";
            break;  
    }

    return $error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my shortened attempt.

```
    $validvals = array('SUBSCRIBE', 'SUB & LIKE', 'LIKE & COMMENT', 'DISLIKE', 'COMMENT', 'LIKE');
    $error = 'false';
    for ($i=0; $i <= 4; $i++)
    {
        if (!in_array(${"act$i"}, $validvals))
        {
            $error = 'true';
            ${"error_0$i"} = 'true';
        }
        else
        {
            ${"error_0${i}"} = 'false';
        }
    }
```

I should clarify that I don't think this is any better than the other suggestions, but I had started writing it before I read them, so figured I would post it.

Comment: This won't work if there end up being more than 9 acts, as it would become `error_010`, `error_011` etc, but that's really just a variable naming issue

Comment: That's a fair point @GrumpyCrouton (and your answer does seem more complete in that way). If expecting more than 9, an extra bit of logic would be required here. I guess the format of the variable does imply a maximum of 99 so I should have accounted for that, but I used the original question's example of 4.

Comment: I don't think it's implied a maxiumum of 99, rather, if it goes over that it would just be `error_100`, etc. The only difference to be made really is if it's under 9

Answer (score -1):

There are few ways:

1. Succinct switch case

   ```
   switch($act1){
       case "SUBSCRIBE":
       case "SUB & LIKE":     
       case "LIKE & COMMENT":   
       case "DISLIKE":  
       case "COMMENT": 
       case "LIKE":
           $error = "false";
           break;      
       default:
           $error = "true";
           $error_01 = "true";
           break;  
       }
   ```
2. For loop as suggested above
3. Create a TRIE of these strings and search within this TRIE. If word is present, set error as false otherwise set it to true

On SqlInjection, always use parameters and avoid dynamic queries. This will take care of SqlInjection

Comment: Your first point is the same code as mine posted 10 minutes prior to yours, your 2nd point is just saying use a loop as suggested in another answer (This does not belong in your answer, as it's already in an answer), and your 3rd point is not explained at all on how to achieve that.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton All I can say that great minds think alike. Many of us answered the same way. On 3rd point, i understand that the TRIE may not be known. However, this shall trigger curiosity in the mind for those. And, I am one of those who upvoted your answer

Answer (score -3):

yup,
you can allow true switch and make condition in case like this

```
switch(true){
     case ($act1=='SUBSCRIBE' and $act2=='SUBSCRIBE' and .....):
     $error = "false";
     break;
     case ($act1=='SUB & LIKE' and $act2=='SUB & LIKE' and .....):
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case ($act1=='LIKE & COMMENT' and $act2=='LIKE & COMMENT' and .....):
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case ($act1=='DISLIKE' and $act2=='DISLIKE' and .....):
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case ($act1=='COMMENT' and $act2=='COMMENT' and .....):
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     case ($act1=='LIKE' and $act2=='LIKE' and .....):
     $error = "false";
     break;      
     default:
    $error = "true";
    $error_01 = "true";
    break;  
 }
```

Comment: This only works if all the acts are the same, otherwise would return an error. This is not a good way to handle this. Not to mention how messy it looks

Comment: Constant expressions in cases are needed and setting error doesn't require `and` on all $act